# Javascript Architecture / Structure

Tags: javascript, architecture

**Update**

**Question:** *When using vanilla Javascript (no frameworks), what is the modern standard practice for project architecture?*

**Answer:** Component based Architecture. This article cleared everything up for me: https://medium.com/@dan.shapiro1210/understanding-component-based-architecture-3ff48ec0c238

---

I have worked with `React JS` for a while and am a little out of touch. I am using ES6 `modules` to `export` and `import` various components, however I do not know how to logically structure the project. Where does the data live? What should handle events etc.

I have build with `MVC` in the past, but that seems a little outdated? Any resources of example builds would be brilliant.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I worked with a monolithic MVC structure before I moved to React, and want to modernise my approach. I have done research, but seem to be getting a little lost.

Comment: @AbdulShaikh how about show some support and actually help with the question. Why have you even bothered with that comment. I think a lot of people have probably gone through the exact same process. React does so much of the hard work for you, it's easy to forget the underlying principles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MVC is perfectly acceptable for single page apps. If you're looking at large scale applications this is a good resource: https://addyosmani.com/largescalejavascript/

Comment: Thank you - just needed to know I wasn't completely heading in the wrong direction.

Answer (score 2):

I still think MVC is a valid pattern and it works well with ES6 modules. I understand the difficulty that you're talking about. Searching for "js patterns" returns older IFE structures which don't talk about data.

Comment: Everything I've read about MVC talks about how it's too tightly coupled. If it's a valid pattern that's used, I'll happily adopt it. Just wanted to do some research first.

Comment: Yeah I guess in that respect MVC is pretty rigid. I don't know why you're getting so many down votes, I think it's a pretty relevant question and I can see your confusion coming from a React stack where data (state) is so abstracted.